# How to match width of a group of columns in a Google Docs table

Tags: google-workspace, google-docs

I'd like to make a group of columns in a table in Google Docs. Is there any way to do this? Something like the Distribute Columns Equally menu item in Microsoft Word?

So far the best I've been able to do is to select the group of columns that I'm interested in and the right-click and in Table Properties set the column width to a specific measurement – which means needing to calculate the measurement that I want. It works but it is tedious (you have to figure out how much width to allocate to the group of columns and then do the math). Seems like there must be a better way…